# How to update signal based on input signal in Angular 17.1

Tags: angular, signals

I have an angular service that is implemented using signals.

```
    export class MyService {
        private idSignal = signal(0);
        setId(id: number) { 
            this.idSignal.set(id);
        }
    }
```

I have a component that injects this service. The component has a required input called id:

```
    export class MyComponent {
       private service = inject(MyService);
       id = input.required<number>();
    }
```

I would like to set the id on the service according to the value of the id input in the component. One option I considered was to use an effect, but it is not recommended to set the value of signals inside effects. How would I do it without breaking best practices, and potentially cause circular dependencies.